# How can I set the compiler:sys.fullName via command line?

Tags: java, install4j

I tried the [commmand line option](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/cli/compiler.html):

```
-D sys.fullName=CustomName
```

but to no effect (empty full name).

The help mentions that only variables defined on the "General Settings->Compiler Variables" step can be overridden like this.

Does that mean I have to create an additional 'intermediate' compiler variable and place it in the Full Name field with `${compiler:intermediate_full_name_variable}`?

(v8.0.11)

I tried the approach with the intermediate compiler variable, but now I have the problem that the localization does not work:

```
-D intermediate_full_name_variable=Custom Name ${i18n:msgkey}
```

Results in "Welcome to Custom Name **messages not found** Setup Assistant". I double checked that the language files and keys exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean I have to create an additional 'intermediate' compiler variable and
> place it in the Full Name field with ${compiler:intermediate_full_name_variable}?

That is correct.

> now I have the problem that the localization does not work:

You could set the "Full name" field to `${i18:myFullName}` and define a message key "myFullName" that includes a compiler variable, like

myFullName=${compiler:productName} Setup Assistant

You can then pass `-D productName=Custom name` on the command line.

Comment: Ah, I wasn’t aware that it is possible to use a compiler variable in the message value. But unfortunately I need a different localized word based on the product type. That‘s why I generated the i18n key into the compiler variable.